# Split cell if there is '%'

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to iterate through each row of the '% interest' column and split at '%' if it is found in that cell, if it is not found I want the code to ignore the cell.

I have tried this:

```
for row in concat_data.index: 
  if (concat_data['% interest'][row]).str.contains('%'):
    concat_data['% interest'] = concat_data['% interest'].str.split('%', expand=True)
```

The error message is

`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` 
I am attaching a picture of the data for better explanation.

[image: Picture of the data]

Thank you!

Comment: `(concat_data['% interest'][row]).str.contains('%')` gives a boolean Series, chain it with `.all` or `.any` according to your logic

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a condition.

Use `str.split(..., expand=True)` and assign the result back to itself and a new column:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"% percent": [ f"25{x}" for x in  ("%","00","00% with interest", " times 3")]})
print(df)

df[["% percent", "new"]] = df["% percent"].str.split("%", expand=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
# before
             % percent
0                  25%
1                 2500
2  2500% with interest
3           25 times 3

# After 
    % percent             new
0          25                
1        2500            None
2        2500   with interest
3  25 times 3            None
```

If you are not interested in the split off part, use it with the original column

```
df["% percent"] = df["% percent"].str.split("%", expand=True)
```

to get

```
    % percent
0          25
1        2500
2        2500
3  25 times 3
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am not interested in the split off part so I used your second piece of code, it works, but it deletes cells that don't have a %. For example, '0.05' becomes ' '.

Comment: @TryingtoCode  that is curious - as you can clearly see I have added a testcase of `'25times 3'` with no % in it and it is preserved in  the output. So better check if you do it exactly like this here or if you deviate from this approach.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, your condition currently returns a series. You need to check a certain condition for each entry. Here is the code.

```
concat_data['% interest'] = concat_data['% interest'].map(lambda x: str(x).split('%')[0])
```

This way, you split the string by % sign, and take everything that comes before it. If there is no % sign in a string, then it returns the string itself. For example,

```
'abc'.split('%') = ['abc']
```

and taking the zero element does the job.

Comment: thank you, this makes sense. When I run the code though it says: AttributeError: 'StringMethods' object has no attribute 'map'